# Arduino IR Led not working

Tags: arduino, infrared

I need major troubleshooting help on this one, and I thank anyone in advance.  This is a little Arduino sketch that is supposed to send a IR impulse to my Sony camera through an IR LED, to trigger the shutter and take a photo. I ultimately plan on connecting it with a RF transmitter so that I can take photos of wildlife from a distance. 
The thing is that this code has worked beautifully in the past, with a motion sensor and a time lapse application as described at http://multifunctionremote.blogspot.com/.
I cannot get it to work anymore.  The RF code and circuit works perfectly in the sense that I get one Arduino to order another Arduino to blink a LED, and so you do not need to be troubled by that.  I just cannot get the IR LED to activate the camera anymore.  The code I am using is at the end of this.  The circuit is extremely simple: a IR LED connected to pin 8 and ground through a 220 Ohm resistor.  For the love of God, it does not work, and I cannot figure out why.  This the troubleshooting I have done:

-Check the camera: it works perfectly with the native, branded IR remote, so that is not the problem
-I haves switched 3 different IR LEDs to sure I was not dealing with a defective one.  I have maximized the output by using a lower Ohm resistor, 100 Ohm.  I have a hard time checking the LED anyway as you cannot see them blinking, but I assume I cannot get 3 defective LEDs!
-The circuit is working, since when I use a red LED instead of the IR LED, it blinks. Does it blink at the right frequency? I cannot tell.
-Is the Arduino defective? I checked all the pins and they work and tested the circuit on two different controllers to no avail.
The only thing that changed since two years ago, when everything worked fine, is the Arduino IDE version I am using.  Has this changed in anyway the firmware on the controller, so that this code doesn’t work anymore?

```
int IRledPin =  8;
void setup() {
pinMode(IRledPin,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
SendChannelUpCode();
delay(3000);
}
void pulseIR(long microsecs) {
   // This is the function dealing with the impulse frequency: we'll count     down from the number of microseconds we are told to wait

  cli();  // this turns off any background interrupts

  while (microsecs > 0) {
   // 38 kHz is about 13 microseconds high and 13 microseconds low
   digitalWrite(IRledPin, HIGH);  // this takes about 3 microseconds to happen
   delayMicroseconds(9);         // hang out for 10 microseconds
   digitalWrite(IRledPin, LOW);   // this also takes about 3 microseconds
   delayMicroseconds(9);         // hang out for 10 microseconds

   // so 26 microseconds altogether
   microsecs -= 26;
  }

  sei();  // this turns them back on
  }
 void SendChannelUpCode() {
```

// This is the code for the shutter release for SONY NEX-7
    pulseIR(2400);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(11000);
    pulseIR(2400);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(600);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(600);
    pulseIR(1200);
    delayMicroseconds(11000);
    }

Comment: That is a lot of reading, too much IMO. Trim it and form paragraphs...

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure that delaymicroseconds() (still) works correctly with interrupts turned off. Other than that, I can't see anything that could have changed significantly.

To have visual feedback regarding the infrared LED, you could place a second LED in series with it and decrease the resistor value. To actually check the IR LED, I suppose you could point it to an IR phototransistor in series with an LED and resistor.

To check the frequency, replace the LED with a red one (or place one in series with it, as said above) and measure how long a pulse of pulseIR(1000000) takes.

I can't think of anything else right now, unless you have access to an oscilloscope.